# Динамическое обновление DIV

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, mysqli

Суть задачи следующая:

Имеется бд MySQL,из которой необходимо брать данные и посредством ajax вставлять определенные значения в дивы. Дело в том,что кол-во обновляемых значений превышает 25шт,потому реализация через индивидуальные php-обработчики не айс.

Т.к ранее не работал с JSON,прошу помощи здесь.

Буду благодарен за конкретные примеры работы с JSON.

Comment: json это строка, определенного формата, сможете на запрос ответить строкой?)

Comment: Как тогда реализовать такое? например, из поля БД X взять значения A,B и вставить значения в Div1 и Div2.

Answer (score 1):

Суть задания не совсем ясна...каким образом данные обновляются и по какому ивенту, но примерно работать должно следущим образом.

У каждого div предполагаемо должен быть уникальный идентификатор, формируем примерно следущий запрос

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "...",
   data: data,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
          //key - ключ определающий нужный div
          $('#ourdiv'+key).html(value);
      });
   },
});
```

Полученые данные в запросе перебираем и вставляем в нужный нам див. Вместо `#ourdiv1` можно использовать, к примеру, `data-id = 1`

Comment: Для уточнения о сути задания: имеется бд с городами и кол-вом населения(для примера). Необходимо брать из таблицы значения и заносить в дивы. Не могу понять,как занести эти данные в массив и затем в див.

Comment: формируете нужный массив...примерно такого вида
`$cities = ['div_id1' => 'data_for_html', 'div_id2' => 'data_for_html', ...]` и возвраще в json `json_encode($cities)`

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. У меня главная проблема состоит именно в помещении этих данных в массив.

Comment: Это уже зависит от логики размещения информации в нужных дивах, если к примеру по областям...то можете после выборки пройтись по всем елементам через for и расперделить. Тут много вариантов

Comment: До выборки еще дойти надо. Я не могу ПОЛУЧИТЬ данные и поместить в массив. т

Comment: Мне кажется вам стоит начать с того что вы можете...почитайте вравила сервиса о том как нужно задавать вопросы и какие, что вы сделали для того чтоб ПОЛУЧИТЬ данные и поместить в массив?